# How to print a sentence based on the the first letter of the word you input (your name)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create some code to give 'random' warm fuzzies/compliments to people based on the first letter in their name. I'm using the dictionary function to hold the information for what compliment goes with each letter. When a (first) letter equals a letter, it will then print the compliment. I'm starting out with the letter A to get the code started and sorted. Once you input your name, it doesn't print the rest of the code.

**Edit:** I'm trying to match the first letter of the input name to the letter in the dictionary which then corresponds to a compliment which it will print. I'm confused as to how to do this.

```py
#Warm fuzzies

def main():
    warm_fuzzies = {'a':'You\'re irresistible when you blush.',
                    'b':'How is it that you always look great, even in sweatpants?',
                    'c':'You have the best ideas.',
                    'd':'Everyone gets knocked down sometimes, but you always get back up and keep going.',
                    'e':'You are a gift to those around you.', 
                    'f':'You are all that and a super-size bag of chips.', 
                    'g':'You are even more beautiful on the inside than you are on the outside.', 
                    'h':'That thing you do not like about yourself is what makes you so interesting.',
                    'i':'You are like a breath of fresh air.', 
                    'j': 'You are someone\'s reason to smile.', 
                    'k':'You\'re even better than a unicorn, because you\'re real.',
                    'l':'You\'re really something special.', 
                    'm':'You deserve a hug right now.',
                    'n':'If someone based an Internet meme on you, it would have impeccable grammar.',
                    'o':'Being around you makes everything better!',
                    'p':'You\'re better than a triple-scoop ice cream cone. With sprinkles.', 
                    'q':'You should be thanked more often. So thank you!!',
                    'r':'You\'re a great example to others.',
                    's':'Your kindness is a balm to all who encounter it.',
                    't':'When you make up your mind about something, nothing stands in your way.', 
                    'u':'The way you treasure your loved ones is incredible.',
                    'v':'You\'re an awesome friend to those around you.', 
                    'w':'You\'re a gift to those around you.', 
                    'x':'When I\'m down you always say something encouraging to help me feel better.',
                    'y':'When I\'m down you always say something encouraging to help me feel better.', 
                    'z':'Our community is better because you\'re in it.'}
    print('What is your name?')
    input_name = input('Insert name here: ')

    n1 = 'a'
    n2 = 'b'
    n3 = 'c'
    n4 = 'd'

    if input_name[0:1] == warm_fuzzies[n1]:
        print(warm_fuzzies['a'])

main()
```

This is the output it gives.:

[image: This is the output it gives.]

I was thinking maybe I could input a .txt file with the info into the dictionary but I don't know how to do that.

How should I go about this? I'm a beginner with Python and thought this would be a cool starter project.

Comment: `if input_name[0:1] == warm_fuzzies[n1]` This comparison is always false.  `input_name[0:1]` is the first letter of whatever the user typed, and `warm_fuzzies[n1]` is _the entire message from the dictionary_.  Of course those two are not equal.

Comment: Thanks. How would I  go about it instead? Any advice? I didn't realise it wouldn't be equal.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `n1`, `n2` etc variables?  Do you _only_ want to print a message if the name starts with one of those?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly it. I thought that if the first letter: input_name[0:1] **First letter here** == warm_fuzzies[n1] equals to the same letter. It would match and then print.

Comment: Just do `print(warm_fuzzies[input_name[0]])`.  There's no need for any comparisons -- just look up the first letter directly.

Comment: If you're going to print whatever message corresponds to the first letter, without caring specifically which letter it is, then I ask again what is the purpose of `n1` `n2` etc.

Comment: Additionally, it may be advisable to include some form of error handling in case an invalid dictionary key is entered. For instance, you could apply the `lower()` function to `input_name[0]` to ensure the program can handle capitalized names.

Comment: I do care what letter it is. I was using the n1 and n2 variable to somehow match it to each other. I don't quite get it myself. I'm just trying to figure out a way for it to work.

Comment: Thanks @Ricardo. I'll also try that.

Comment: `print(warm_fuzzies.get((c:=input('Input a name: ').lower()[0]), f'Sorry, no entry for: {c}'))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    #Warm fuzzies

def main():
    warm_fuzzies = {'a':'You\'re irresistible when you blush.',
                    'b':'How is it that you always look great, even in sweatpants?',
                    'c':'You have the best ideas.',
                    'd':'Everyone gets knocked down sometimes, but you always get back up and keep going.',
                    'e':'You are a gift to those around you.', 
                    'f':'You are all that and a super-size bag of chips.', 
                    'g':'You are even more beautiful on the inside than you are on the outside.', 
                    'h':'That thing you do not like about yourself is what makes you so interesting.',
                    'i':'You are like a breath of fresh air.', 
                    'j': 'You are someone\'s reason to smile.', 
                    'k':'You\'re even better than a unicorn, because you\'re real.',
                    'l':'You\'re really something special.', 
                    'm':'You deserve a hug right now.',
                    'n':'If someone based an Internet meme on you, it would have impeccable grammar.',
                    'o':'Being around you makes everything better!',
                    'p':'You\'re better than a triple-scoop ice cream cone. With sprinkles.', 
                    'q':'You should be thanked more often. So thank you!!',
                    'r':'You\'re a great example to others.',
                    's':'Your kindness is a balm to all who encounter it.',
                    't':'When you make up your mind about something, nothing stands in your way.', 
                    'u':'The way you treasure your loved ones is incredible.',
                    'v':'You\'re an awesome friend to those around you.', 
                    'w':'You\'re a gift to those around you.', 
                    'x':'When I\'m down you always say something encouraging to help me feel better.',
                    'y':'When I\'m down you always say something encouraging to help me feel better.', 
                    'z':'Our community is better because you\'re in it.'}
                    
    result = ""
    for letter in input_name:
        result += warm_fuzzies.get(letter, " ") + " "
    return result.strip()

print('What is your name?')

input_name = input('Insert name here: ')

fuzzy_result = main()
print(fuzzy_result)
```

Comment: Hey, it worker after I tweeked it a bit so it only correlate the first letter to the dictionary. Not every letter in the name. Thanks :)

Comment: No Problem! In the future if you want to use the key in value in a dictionary, loop over it using a for loop or in this case, looping over the name

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you want to do.

```
letter_to_compliment_dict = {}    # The huge dict that you have in the code.
name = input("Enter your name: ")
# We need the first letter of the name, we may want to remove any extra whitespace at   the beginning
first_letter = name.strip()[0].casefold()   # strip removes any whitespace at the beginning and 
# the end of the string (default is whitespace, you can change that). 
# Then we casefold (or lower) the first letter since all the letters are lowered in the dictionary

compliment = letter_to_compliment_dict.get(first_letter, "I do not have a compliment for this letter")    # Get will try to get a value using first_letter, if it does not exist, it will return the second argument.
print(compliment)
```

The use of [0:1] is unnecessary and you should instead use [0].
I assume that the use of n1, n2, n3 is to add 26 if-checks and print the value accordingly. But you do not need to use that and this is the advantage of using dictionary. Also, instead of comparing the first letter to the value returned by the dictionary, compare it to n1, n2 if you really want to compare. But again, that is why a dictionary is even useful.
The use of `main` function in python is not necessary. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a dictionary lookup for the first letter of their name:

```
# Prompt the user for their name and store it in `input_name`
input_name = input('Insert name here: ')

# Get the first letter of the input name and make sure it's lowercase with a call to `lower()`
first_letter = input_name[0].lower()

# Check if the name entered was valid
if first_letter in warm_fuzzies:
    print(warm_fuzzies[first_letter])
else:
    print("Your name doesn't start with a letter of the english alphabet!")
```